# JS for DIV to display if published after a certain date

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

There are some vintage answers but they seem to be based on the client date.

I simply need a DIV to display if the **posted** (published) date of the article is on or after 2/25/2017. Platform=Google Blogger so no PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code you have.

Comment: JavaScript If statements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: <h3>Related content:</h3><br /><br />
<script async='async' src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Matched Content -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"style="display:block"data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"data-ad-format="autorelaxed"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>

Here's the problem. I have this assigned to a KDE hot key but I have other contributors. I want to embed it into the template BUT, I need a conditional date or it will duplicate itself prior to the date that I add it to the template.